# How to create a method that accepts a callback function in java?

Tags: java, asynchronous

I created a distributed lock class that I designed to be used like this:

```
myLock.lock();
doSomething();
myLock.unlock();
```

In my current implementation, lock() blocks until the lock is acquired. But I am running into some deadlock issues with this implementation. So I'd like to rewrite it to be asynchronous, but I have no idea how to do that in java.

Something like this would work I think:

```
myLock.lock(myCallbackFunction);

private void myCallbackFunction(boolean result){
    if(result){
        doSomething();
        mylock.Unlock();
    }
}
```

Is there a way to do this in java?

EDIT (More detail): The reasons why the synchronous implementation is deadlocking are complicated and not relevant. The distributed lock is acquiring mutual exclusion of a resource across a network with multiple systems. Really the only thing I'm looking for is how to write a method that accepts a callback function.

Comment: "So I'd like to rewrite it to be asynchronous" - A lock is synchronous by definition. What do you mean by "I'd like to rewrite it to be asynchronous"?

Comment: Have you seen [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gkkqg.html)?

Comment: You should provide more details about these methods. When exactly are you getting the deadlock?

Comment: You need to start a thread, or use one of the thread pool facilities.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't do that in Java yet. What you *can* do is define a `LockCallback` interface:

```
interface LockCallback {
  void run(boolean result, MyLock lock);
}
```

and have `MyLock#lock` take a `LockCallback` as a parameter. Then callers can call it as

```
myLock.lock(new LockCallback {
  public void run(boolean result, MyLock lock) {
    // ... do whatever needs to be done ...
    lock.unlock();
  });
```

Lambda syntax in Java 8 should make this a little less ugly looking.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of writing your own and then abandoning the idea because you couldn't make it work, why not use a [Semaphore](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Semaphore.html), which is already there and is implemented correctly?

Comment: Still doesn't make anything asynchronous.

Comment: @HotLicks: True, but while the question's title is about asynchronous methods, that's not what the content of the question talks about.